# No default proposals for protractor browser.actions() and throws TypeError: browser.actions(...).dragAndDrop(...).perfrom is not a function

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor Version 5.4.2 in window 10 OS, to script I use Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.Version: Photon Release (4.8.0) with Tern plugin.

I get no default proposals for browser.actions(). Also my execution is fails due to below error .

> Message:
>       Failed: browser.actions(...).dragAndDrop(...).perfrom is not a function
>     Stack:
>       TypeError: browser.actions(...).dragAndDrop(...).perfrom is not a function
>           at UserContext. (F:\Learning\Repositories\protractor-sam-test-scripts\EclipsePro\src\com\sam\scriptjs\draganddrop.spec.js:15:45)
>           at C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:112:25
>           at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1077:7)
>           at ControlFlow.promise (C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2505:12)
>           at schedulerExecute (C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:95:18)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
>           at asyncRun (C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2974:25)
>           at C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
>           at 
>       From: Task: Run it("Drag and drop") in control flow
>           at UserContext. (C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:19)
>       From asynchronous test:
>       Error
>           at Suite. (F:\Learning\Repositories\protractor-sam-test-scripts\EclipsePro\src\com\sam\scriptjs\draganddrop.spec.js:11:4)
>           at Object. (F:\Learning\Repositories\protractor-sam-test-scripts\EclipsePro\src\com\sam\scriptjs\draganddrop.spec.js:2:1)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)

I already updated my `protractor` and `webdriver-manager` versions , but the error still persists.

Please see my `spec.js`

```
//draganddrop.spec.js
describe('drag and drop trial', function() {


      //Each single it function is a test script
      it('first spec', function() {
          browser.driver.get('https://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#!/');
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Drag and Drop for AngularJS');
      });

      it('Drag and drop', function() {
           var from=element(by.model('list1'));
           var to=element(by.model('list2'));
          //drag and drop source  to Destination
           browser.actions().dragAndDrop(from,to).perfrom();
           browser.sleep(7500);
          });

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
    //1st way: dragging one element to another
    browser.actions().mouseDown(from).mouseMove(to).mouseUp().perform();
```

There are 3 ways of implementing dragAndDrop in which I found this approach in protractor the most fitting.

Comment: Thank you Puja Bhattacharya. it worked even though it's not listed as a suggestion . Have a nice day .

Comment: @SameeraDeSilva: yeah, so i put a short tutorial for more on this: https://medium.com/@pujabhattacharya/3-ways-to-drag-and-drop-using-protractor-c29917f67443 it has implementation code as well.